# How many times can one receive the AWS free tier?

Tags: amazon-web-services

I currently have an account with AWS and I am using the free tier which lasts for 12 months, and then all usage after this 12 month period on this account will be billed at the standard rate.

However I am still in initial testing with AWS so is it possible to create a new account and receive the 12 month free tier again or is it some how tied to the credit card/personal information so that a single user cannot receive it more than once?

Comment: There are ways to reset free tier without creating new account. Read between the lines here, look around and you may find one. Sorry, cannot give you specifics. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to create a new account but not with the free benefits they will be able to track it via the Credit card and your Machine ID

To quote the AWS Policy it says

**"You will not be eligible for the Offer if you or your organization create(s) more than one account to receive additional benefits under the Offer,You will be charged standard rates for use of AWS services if we determine that you are not eligible for the Offer."**

All the information

https://aws.amazon.com/free/terms/

Therefore, you can only receive the AWS free tier once per your registered card , email address and MAC Address

Comment: Do you have any reference for AWS tracking Mac or machine id for this purpose?

Comment: My question would be how do they track it? As all of the methods seen above can be altered.